# html Body Content Overlapping with header if header height is more than 210px

Tags: html, printing

Im trying to develop html with sticky header and footer at all pages...

This Source [Ultimate printable HTML layout with repeating header & footer on every page](https://plnkr.co/edit/lWk6Yd?preview) is best example i could find for actaully applicable but im facing a small issue with it

**Im converting the HTML string to A4 Size paper for printing the document...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
/* Styles go here */

.page-header, .page-header-space {
  height: 100px;
}

.page-footer, .page-footer-space {
  height: 50px;

}

.page-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid black; /* for demo */
  background: yellow; /* for demo */
}

.page-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0mm;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; /* for demo */
  background: yellow; /* for demo */
}

.page {
  page-break-after: always;
}

@page {
     size: A4;
     margin: 5 auto;
     }

@media print {
   thead {display: table-header-group;} 
   tfoot {display: table-footer-group;}

   button {display: none;}

   body {margin: 0;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="page-header" style="text-align: center">
    I'm The Header
    <br/>
    <button type="button" onClick="window.print()" style="background: pink">
      PRINT ME!
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="page-footer">
    I'm The Footer
  </div>

  <table>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--place holder for the fixed-position header-->
          <div class="page-header-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--*** CONTENT GOES HERE ***-->
          <div class="page">PAGE 1</div>
          <div class="page">PAGE 2</div>
          <div class="page" style="line-height: 3;">
            PAGE 3 - Long Content
            <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt metus eu consectetur rutrum. Praesent tempor facilisis dapibus. Aliquam cursus diam ac vehicula pulvinar. Integer lacinia non odio et condimentum. Aenean faucibus cursus
            mi, sed interdum turpis sagittis a. Quisque quis pellentesque mi. Ut erat eros, posuere sed scelerisque ut, pharetra vitae tellus. Suspendisse ligula sapien, laoreet ac hendrerit sit amet, viverra vel mi. Pellentesque faucibus nisl et dolor
            pharetra, vel mattis massa venenatis. Integer congue condimentum nisi, sed tincidunt velit tincidunt non. Nulla sagittis sed lorem pretium aliquam. Praesent consectetur volutpat nibh, quis pulvinar est volutpat id. Cras maximus odio posuere
            suscipit venenatis. Donec rhoncus scelerisque metus, in tempus erat rhoncus sed. Morbi massa sapien, porttitor id urna vel, volutpat blandit velit. Cras sit amet sem eros. Quisque commodo facilisis tristique. Proin pellentesque sodales rutrum.
            Vestibulum purus neque, congue vel dapibus in, venenatis ut felis. Donec et ligula enim. Sed sapien sapien, tincidunt vitae lectus quis, ultricies rhoncus mi. Nunc dapibus nulla tempus nunc interdum, sed facilisis ex pellentesque. Nunc vel
            lorem leo. Cras pharetra sodales metus. Cras lacus ex, consequat at consequat vel, laoreet ac dui. Curabitur aliquam, sapien quis congue feugiat, nisi nisl feugiat diam, sed vehicula velit nulla ac nisl. Aliquam quis nisi euismod massa blandit
            pharetra nec eget nunc. Etiam eros ante, auctor sit amet quam vel, fringilla faucibus leo. Morbi a pulvinar nulla. Praesent sed vulputate nisl. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean commodo
            mollis iaculis. Maecenas consectetur enim vitae mollis venenatis. Ut scelerisque pretium orci id laoreet. In sit amet pharetra diam. Vestibulum in molestie lorem. Nunc gravida, eros non consequat fermentum, ex orci vestibulum orci, non accumsan
            sem velit ac lectus. Vivamus malesuada lacus nec velit dignissim, ac fermentum nulla pretium. Aenean mi nisi, convallis sed tempor in, porttitor eu libero. Praesent et molestie ante. Duis suscipit vitae purus sit amet aliquam. Vestibulum lectus
            justo, lobortis a purus a, dapibus efficitur metus. Suspendisse potenti. Duis dictum ex lorem. Suspendisse nec ligula consectetur magna hendrerit ullamcorper et eget mauris. Etiam vestibulum sodales diam, eget venenatis nunc luctus quis. Ut
            fermentum placerat neque nec elementum. Praesent orci erat, rhoncus vitae est eu, dictum molestie metus. Cras et fermentum elit. Aenean eget augue lacinia, varius ante in, ullamcorper dolor. Cras viverra purus non egestas consectetur. Nulla
            nec dolor ac lectus convallis aliquet sed a metus. Suspendisse eu imperdiet nunc, id pulvinar risus. Maecenas varius sagittis est, vel fermentum risus accumsan at. Vestibulum sollicitudin dui pharetra sapien volutpat, id convallis mi vestibulum.
            Phasellus commodo sit amet lorem quis imperdiet. Proin nec diam sed urna euismod ultricies at sed urna. Quisque ornare, nulla et vehicula ultrices, massa purus vehicula urna, ac sodales lacus leo vitae mi. Sed congue placerat justo at placerat.
            Aenean suscipit fringilla vehicula. Quisque iaculis orci vitae arcu commodo maximus. Maecenas nec nunc rutrum, cursus elit quis, porttitor sapien. Sed ac hendrerit ipsum, lacinia fringilla velit. Donec ultricies feugiat dictum.
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--place holder for the fixed-position footer-->
          <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

if

```
.page-header, .page-header-space {
  height: 210px;
}
```

its working perfect but if i give the height more than 210 / 220 px
for example

```
.page-header, .page-header-space {
  height: 250px;
}
```

the content of the body is hidding behand the header...
what could be the possible solution to overcome the problem.

Example of the error from actual output
**Output with 210px or Below**

[image: expected Output for all pages]

**Output with 250px**

[image: Overlapping Content with header]
Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: Please include a [mre] of the code here on Stack Overflow. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the questions editor toolbar) to do so.

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which also includes your HTML code? The CSS alone tells us nothing at this moment

Comment: sure! i min sir

Comment: @TadWohlrapp, included thanks

Comment: Running your code in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) I don't see any issues occurring, when changing the height from 210 to 250px or so. What am I missing?
Also I'm not sure what the screenshots are supposed to show...

Comment: @TadWohlrapp im converting the html string to A4 size paper, 
the first screenshot is the expected output but the second screen shot is what im facing prob with if i keep height to 250px

Comment: Wait, so that's an issue when _printing_ the document on a printer? If so, you might wanna add that to the question..

Comment: yes, while printing the document.. i would like to add this to the question!!

Comment: Then do so, there's an [edit] button below your question ;)

Comment: @TadWohlrapp thank you! updated :)

Comment: Now I see the problem. That's an interesting one

Comment: @TabWohlrapp sir, any possible solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213221/discussion-between-ayush-agarwal-and-tad-wohlrapp).